# Why sizeof behaves differently for an double pointer and a double array?

Tags: c++, pointers

I wrote a code a fragment of which is shown below. I don't understand why it does not print 800 for the pointer variable p.

```
double *p = new double [100];
double q[10];
printf("Sizeof(p) = %d\n", sizeof(p)); // prints 4
printf("Sizeof(q) = %d\n", sizeof(q)); // prints 80
```

I understand why it prints 80 for q (8 bytes/double * 10) but why not 800 for p? An associated question would be, how does the compiler know how much space to deallocate when it encounters the delete for p?

```
delete [] p;
```

Comment: All pointers have the same size. A pointer is a memory address, and all the address have the same size.

Comment: re the associated question: The details are unspecified, but logically the system will have to maintain some sort of map of addresses to allocation sizes (and probably other metadata) that is used by both `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the actual pointer address is stored in 4 bytes. If you wanted the size of what `p` points to, you would say:

```
sizeof(*p);
```

Comment: `sizeof(*p)` most likely is 8.

Comment: I actually want to know how can the compiler know how much space has been allocated to p previously? What function can be used in a code? Like getMemoryAllocated( p ) and it prints 800 (for 8 * 100 bytes).